# How to adjust title size or banner size of a single slide in xaringan

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I have encountered an issue with the size of banner title as in the following picture.

[image]

It is two-line title, which does not fit into the banner.
Is there any way to make the banner size bigger (vertically increased) or to make font size of title smaller.

I would appreciate it if you could show me both ways. Thanks.

My code is

````
---
title: "Lecture"
subtitle: "subtitle"
author: "Instructor"
institute: "University"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    seal: false
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      titleSlideClass: [top, left]
 
---
class: title-slide, top, left, inverse
background-image: url(aaa.jpeg)
background-size: cover

# *`r rmarkdown::metadata$title`*
## *`r rmarkdown::metadata$subtitle`*
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$author`
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$institute`
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$date`
### `r Sys.Date()`

```{css, echo=FALSE}
<style>
.remark-slide-content.hljs-default {
  border-top: 40px solid #23373B;
}

.remark-slide-content > h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: -85px;
}

</style>
```

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

---

# Why people are constantly switching jobs, causing frictional unemployment?

---
````

The updated version of problematic page is written in the following way:

````
---
class: custom
```{css, echo=FALSE}
.remark-slide-content .hljs-default {
  border-top: 40px solid #23373B;
}

.remark-slide-content > h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: -85px;
}

.custom h1 {
font-size: 24px;
}
```
# Causes of unemployment: Why people are constantly switching jobs, causing frictional unemployment?

### .my-style1[Sectoral shifts]

### .my-style1[Structural shifts]

### Seasonal changes

### Taste shocks

---
````

Comment: In your updated case its not working that's because you have not give any space between the css chunk's  "```" and `# Causes of unemployment: Why........`. Add some spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define CSS rule for a specific slide (It might be to change the title font size of that specific slide or to do anything), define a `class: your-class-name` just after creating a new slide with the `---`.

So to change the title font size of that single slide, we write `class: custom` just after `---` and then define CSS rule in css chunk for `.custom` to reduce the font-size.

````
---
title: "Lecture"
subtitle: "subtitle"
author: "Instructor"
institute: "University"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    seal: false
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
 
---
class: title-slide, top, left, inverse
background-image: url(lights.jpg)
background-size: cover

# *`r rmarkdown::metadata$title`*
## *`r rmarkdown::metadata$subtitle`*
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$author`
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$institute`
### `r Sys.Date()`


```{css, echo=FALSE}
.remark-slide-content .hljs-default {
  border-top: 40px solid #23373B;
}

.remark-slide-content > h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: -85px;
}

.custom h1 {
font-size: 24px;
}
```


---
class: custom

# Why people are constantly switching jobs, causing frictional unemployment?

---

# Heres another slide title
````

Comment: Does **css chunk** mean the code in the `.css` file and define the new font size with `.my-style[]`?

Comment: by css chunk I meant ```{css echo=FALSE}  ``` and define font size for class: custom

Comment: I just add `.custom h1 {font-size: 24px;}` like you did, but it won't change anything. Maybe it is because  the slide with lengthy title is one of pages in the middle instead of the first page?

Comment: you have to add `class: custom` just after the three dash sign `---` for that specific slide, it doesn't matter whether the slide comes first or middle. [See this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan-format.html#slides-and-properties) to get the idea.